# android - android:maxLines="3" cuts off at 2

Tags: android, lines

Here is my view

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/textView1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:background="#ff000000" 
        android:gravity="center"/>
```

The maxLines makes enough room for 3 lines...even if you do the following

```
//Needed code to cast TextView omitted for simplicity
txtView.setLines(3);
//and
txtView.setMaxLines(3);
```

They still have the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known bug. See details and how to solve it [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2254).

Answer (score 1):

adding a `android:lines="3"` attribute works
copying a working code from eclipse:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:background="#ff000000" 
        android:gravity="center"  android:lines="3"/>
```

Comment: added the android:lines and it still shows 2 lines...it makes space for 3

Comment: can you show me an eg string which you are trying to put in there? because i tried this and it shows 3-line text to me.